# Angular Dart Tutorial section 5 - 'self.injector$Injector'

Tags: angular, routes, dart

In the Tour of Heroes tutorial, Section 5, `main.dart` contains the following line:

> final InjectorFactory injector = self.injector$Injector;

Is this a typo? It's giving me a warning in VSCode.

Comment: What's the warning?

Comment: The warning is "The getter 'injector$Injector' isn't defined for the class 'self'.

Comment: Can you please add a link to the tutorial?

Comment: [link](https://webdev.dartlang.org/angular/tutorial/toh-pt5#make-the-router-available)

Comment: The missing code should be generated when you run `webdev serve` or `webdev build`

Comment: Both `webdev serve` and `webdev build` complete with no errors. The page with the app title shows, but without a list of heroes. I'll need to read up on the Dart language to understand the syntax better. Thanks for your help.

Comment: I think you can ignore the warning then. Heros not showing is orobably something else.

Answer (score 3):

I was having the same problem, as it complete with no errors, I just added the following on **analysis_options.yaml** to ignore the error.

```
analyzer:
  errors:
    undefined_getter: ignore
```