# Angular Dart is giving error : The getter 'injector$Injector' isn't defined for the class 'self'

Tags: dart, angular-dart

I am just trying Routing in Angular Dart. I was following this https://webdev.dartlang.org/angular/guide/router/1 guide but I am getting an error.

This line is giving error `final InjectorFactory injector = self.injector$Injector;`  and the error is `The getter 'injector$Injector' isn't defined for the class 'self`.

```
import 'package:angular/angular.dart';
import 'package:angular_router/angular_router.dart';
import '../src/app_component.template.dart' as ng;

import 'main.template.dart' as self;

const useHashLS = false;
@GenerateInjector(routerProvidersHash)

final InjectorFactory injector = self.injector$Injector;
// The getter 'injector$Injector' isn't defined for the class 'self' 

void main() {
  runApp(ng.AppComponentNgFactory, createInjector: injector);
}
```

Comment: same problem here, any progress?

Answer (score 2):

> I was having the same problem, as it complete with no errors, I just
>   added the following on analysis_options.yaml to ignore the error.
>
> ```
> analyzer:
>   errors:
>     undefined_getter: ignore
> ```

Answer by https://stackoverflow.com/a/53304768/2997534

Answer (score 1):

I stumbled upon a workaround without ignoring the analyzer:

```
import 'main.template.dart' show injector$Injector;

@GenerateInjector(routerProvidersHash)
final InjectorFactory injector = injector$Injector;
```

Showing the `injector$Injector` seems to fix the error.

Answer (score 0):

This can be fixed by restarting the app. If your app is running then stop it and restart using the command `webdev serve`. For more information you can refer
[here](https://github.com/angulardart/angular/issues/1716)

Answer (score -1):

I think it is just because the `@GenerateInjector` annotation is not directly above the injector